# compressed encrypted file is bigger then source

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycrypto

I created a encrypted file from a text file in python with beefish.
beefish uses pycrypto.

so my source text file is 33742 bytes and the encrypted version is 33752.
thats ok so far but ...

when I compress the test.enc (encrypted test file) with tar -czvf the final file is 33989 bytes. Why does the compression not work when the source file is encrypted?

So far the only option then seems to compress it first and then encrypt it cause then the file stays that small.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Compression works by identifying patterns in the data. Since you can't identify patterns in encrypted data (that's the whole point), you can't compress it.

For a perfect encryption algorithm that produced a 33,742 byte output, ideally all you would be able to determine about the decrypted original data is that it can fit in 33,742 bytes, but no more than that. If you could compress it to, say, 31,400 bytes, then you would immediately know the input data was not, say, 32,000 bytes of random data since random data is patternless and thus incompressible. That would indicate a failure on the part of the encryption scheme. It's nobody's business whether the decrypted data is random or not.

Comment: *'patterns in compressed data'*: did you mean 'patterns in encrypted data' instead perhaps?

Comment: thanks for updating your post with more details on that. I will compress it first and then encrypted. deciding that wasnt my problem but I wondered about the result after compressing an encrypted file and you and Martijn wrote two great answers on that. thanks dave

Answer (score 1):

The compression method used by tar -z relies on repeating patterns in the input file, replacing these patterns by a count of how many times the pattern repeated (grossly simplified).

However, when you encrypt a file, you are basically trying to hide any repeating patterns in as much 'random'-looking noise as possible. That makes your file nearly incompressible. Combine that with the overhead of the archive and compression file format (metadata, etc.) and your file actually ends up slightly larger instead.

You should reverse the process; compress first, *then* encrypt, and you'll increase the chances you end up with a smaller payload significantly.

Comment: so is compress first and then encrypt the better solution? the compression is worth cause it saves 4 times the space in average for the files its used on.

Comment: Yes, tar header is 512 bytes with about 100-200 bytes worth of non-zero characters.

Comment: @dave: yes, I'd say compression first, followed by encryption, can lead to a smaller payload.